# Continuous Delivery

Tags: continuous-integration

Is it possible to implement continuous delivery in Salesforce? By "continuous delivery", I mean that the build, test and deployment steps that occur from the time that code is checked in to the time it is released in production are fully (or nearly fully) automated.

Comment: Yes. Here's a DX video from the ISV enablement team discussing how this works using the DX CLI that is worth a watch. It can also be done with non-DX workflows in a similar fashion. https://youtu.be/xLjY-j5pf6c

Comment: @Aaron, there is even a [Trailhead Module that covers the subject](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/heroku-flow), enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is **Yes**. There are multiple resources available on how to implement a CI/CD (Continuous Integration/Continuous Delivery) for Salesforce using different tools. However, you should carefully review your CD requirements for Production.

CD can be desirable say until UAT, but you may not want to deliver to Production with every sprint/phase depending on your delivery methodology until you have Business User sign off and that you are certain that you are pushing a clean code not breaking any functionality that was released earlier.

Even for UAT, where you will have end users testing the application, you may not want to deliver as CD. Consider a testing in progress and with a new check-in the CI/CD process kicks in, and deploys to UAT potentially pushing a new feature which overrode the last one without being tested completely.

This [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Continuous_Integration_How-To) is a good place to start with CI/CD topic in Salesforce. You can also find references if you search the web.

Comment: To be honest, I believe "YES for CI" and "Not yet" for CD. At least not without using third party tools.

Comment: @ChristianSzandorKnapp Agree. CD should not be automated without carefully reviewing the needs. I have often had people say/think that CI enables CD, whereas they are completely different things to implement.